# Stop and start a setInterval in a ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I am currently making a React app which fetches datas from an API every second to update itself.
I'm then displaying a table with these datas that refreshes every second.

My current issue is that I have to allow the user to click on a td, thus stopping the timer, allowing him to edit.
And then start the timer again once he is done.

I can stop it but I don't know how to restart it once it has stopped. Here is my code:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => (axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000?count=20")
      .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.data }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))), 1000)
  }

  stopTimer = () => {
    console.log("stoooop")
    clearInterval(this.timer)
  }

  launchTimer = () => {
    ???
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = this.launchTimer();
  }

  stopTimer = () => {
    console.log("stoooop");
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  };

  launchTimer = () => {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => (axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000?count=20")
      .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.data }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))), 1000);
  };
```

Comment: Oh of course, I was stuck in my weird logic of doing it all in the componentDidMount and didn't even think about that.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
       data: [],
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = launchTimer();
}

stopTimer = () => {
   console.log("stoooop")
   clearInterval(this.timer)
}

launchTimer = () => {
    setInterval(() => (axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000?count=20")
      .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.data }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))), 1000)
}
```